# How can I stop water from coming out of the shower head even when the diverter valve is shut on the tub faucet spout?

Tags: shower

We just had the tub faucet with diverter valve spout replaced.  It is the two valve wall mounted type faucet.  Now when you open either or both faucet valves water comes out of the shower no matter whether the diverter is up or down on the spout. I pulled off the spout with diverter and put another brand new one on and the same thing happens.  What can cause this and how can I fix it?

Comment: Can you post a picture of the setup? It sounds like the diverter is somehow being connected incorrectly, which would easily cause the issue.

Comment: There are two types of shower/tub diverter--one is in the spout and the other is in the valve body inside the wall. Which do you have?

Comment: If we expect the OP to post pictures, they need enough rep to do it in the first place. As such +1

Comment: If you remove the spout from the water line and turn it on does the shower still drip?

Comment: If you take off the whole spout does water still come out of the shower?

Answer (score 1):

Could be that your diverter is not closing all the way. Without a picture.....I assume the shower attaches to the tub spout. If so, the diverter is not closing all the way or the diverter may have something blocking it from closing all the way.

Comment: I have seen excessive solder cause this on sweated fittings for the type with the diverter in the spout, I am thinking that PFTE tape could also cause the problem. I would thread a nipple into the faucet if it is the screw on type or remove the spout if copper slide on type and see if water flows out the unrestricted pipe. If water still goes to the shower head there is a blockage of some type causing the water to go up.

Comment: `..see if water flows out the unrestricted pipe.` This ^